# InfoPath 2010 form not generating new data in Form Library

Tags: infopath

I have successfully published two InfoPath forms to my VM, however, one is saving the data in the form library and one is not.  I checked the submit properties and both are the same.

I've searched several answers and fixed things I've found but to no avail.  Form seems like it is going thru but it really is not.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a "button" to submit data? If so you need to click on the button and then under the rules tab select the submit option.

You have the default Publish button when you create InfoPath forms. If that is not working as well then you need to recheck the publish and submit options of your form.